# CSS: How do I make the lines in this hover effect stay with the word inside of it?

Tags: css

This is my [modification of someone else's hover effect](http://codepen.io/Hello911/pen/PWoORd?editors=0100). So I am not familiar with the working of btn-2 class.(I don't know the syntax used)

Here is my CSS code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: .6s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: tomato;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  }

.container { 

  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center; 
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.btn-2 {
    letter-spacing: 10px;
}

.btn-2:hover,
.btn-2:active {
  letter-spacing: 30px;
}

.btn-2:after,
.btn-2:before {
  
  border: 1px solid rgba(tomato, 0);
  bottom: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 280ms ease-in-out;
  width: 0;
}

.btn-2:hover:after,
.btn-2:hover:before {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-color: tomato;
  transition: width 350ms ease-in-out;
  width: 50%;
}

.btn-2:hover:before {
  bottom: auto;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
}
```

I want to use the effect for button in my navigation bar. But I have 3 problems to solve:

1. I want the lines above and below the word that appear when you hover it to be of the same width as the word.
2. I want the word to be centered relative to the line. That is, the line should grow out from the middle point of the word.
3. The lines isn't going where the word is going.

Some discoveries I make, which I don't know the cause of:

1. The 2 lines will be longer when .comtainer{padding=1em} than 5em.
2. When I delete text-align and vertical-align in the .container class, the hovering lines stay centered, but the word goes to the left of the window.

Comment: can you also add html?

Comment: A jsfiddle of what you have so far would greatly help in allowing the community to assist you in finding a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how good I understand you, but here some example I made

```
a {
  color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none; 
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  &:before,
  &:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #333;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  }
  &:before {
     top:0;
  }
   &:after {
     bottom: 0;
   }
   &:hover {
     letter-spacing: 5px;
     &:before,
     &:after {
       width: 100%;
     }
   }
   //Trick is here
   span {
    &:before {
      content:attr(title);;
      letter-spacing: 5px;
      display:block;
      height:1px;
      color:transparent;
      overflow:hidden;
      visibility:hidden;
      margin-bottom:-1px;
    }
  }
}


<a href="#" class="btn"><span title="Hover Me">Hover Me</span></a>
```

You can check my example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vladavip88/g9urx28L/1/)

Comment: Can you explain the trick is here part? What each line of code does? I need to know how those 2 lines appear and disappear? I think its a rectangle rotating around y-axis, with only its top and bottom border shown.

Comment: Hi, I will try to explain you how it's work. This method doesn't include borders at all. In this example I used :before and :after selectors which allow you to add content before and after element. So before and after element I added container with width of 0px and height of 2px which are centered in middle. So on hover I just change their width to 100% of parent element. Trick with span element we need because we don't want to define button width, we want it to be dynamic. Span is invisible placeholder to button which will be same width as spreaded text. This allow us to center text.